# Laravel not redirecting to route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to validate some data from a form and redirect the user to the page with any errors if any. My code doesn't redirect to any route. The routing for all of my routes works correctly. I echoed the input with Input::all() and it does have the user input. The validator works as well. I'm not sure exactly what's preventing the Redirect::route from working

```
public function postPurchase()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'condition' => 'required',
        'memory' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'accessories' => 'required',
        'shipping' => 'required'
    ));

    // $input = Input::all();
    // dd($input);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // echo "string";
        return Redirect::route('home');

    } else {
        echo "this succedded";
    }
    //Get prices, item id, etc and send user to checkout page
    // echo "Get prices, item id, etc and send user to checkout page";
}
```

This is the code that precede the postPurchase method:

```
public function getPurchase()
    {
        return View::make('general.purchase');
    }

    public function getCheckout()
    {
        return View::make('general.checkout');
    }

    public function postPurchaseCheck()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $this->input = $input;

        if (Input::get('buy')) {
            $this->postPurchase();
        }
        elseif (Input::get('cart')) {
            $this->postAddCart();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Can you also post your `routes.php` file content?

Answer (score 2):

You call the function - but you dont 'return' the Redirect that is given back to you.

Change

```
if (Input::get('buy')) {
            $this->postPurchase();
        }
```

to

```
if (Input::get('buy')) {
            return $this->postPurchase();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating this

```
if (Input::get('buy')) {
            return $this->postPurchase();
 } elseif (Input::get('cart')) {
   return $this->postAddCart();
}
```

and

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
        // echo "string";
        return Redirect::to('home');

    } else {
        echo "this succedded";
    }
```

also don't forget to define it on route file

Answer (score 0):

Change you postPurchaseCheck() method to return what is returned by $this->postPurchase() like this. Because you are calling the postPurchase() method internally but post is happening on postPurchaseCheck() method so redirect has to be returned by the method that handle POST request

```
public function postPurchaseCheck()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $this->input = $input;

    if (Input::get('buy')) {
       return $this->postPurchase();
    }
    elseif (Input::get('cart')) {
       return $this->postAddCart();
    }

}
```